# WSO2 IS: How to add SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, wso2, certificate, ssl-certificate, wso2-identity-server

I've done following steps

1. Create keystore:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias wso2carbon -keyalg RSA -keystore wso2carbon.jks -keysize 2048
   ```
2. Crete certificate request:

   ```
   keytool -certreq -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -storepass wso2carbon
   ```
3. Bought Comodo PositiveSSL certificate
4. Import all certificates to newly created keystore - wso2carbon.jks:

   ```
   keytool -import -alias root -keystore wso2carbon.jks -trustcacerts -file AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt -storepass wso2carbon

   keytool -import -alias intermediate1 -keystore wso2carbon.jks -trustcacerts -file COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt -storepass wso2carbon

   keytool -import -alias intermediate2 -keystore wso2carbon.jks -trustcacerts -file COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt -storepass wso2carbon

   keytool -import -alias domain.com -keystore wso2carbon.jks -trustcacerts -file domain_com.crt -storepass wso2carbon
   ```
5. Copied wso2carbon.jks to {CARBON_HOME}/repository/resources/security/ and overwrite the old one.
6. Restarted WSO2 IS. WHen I inspect with prowser it says in Certificate hiararchy only domain.com is present.

In general I followed this tutorial https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS521/Creating+New+Keystores#CreatingNewKeystores-Creatingakeystoreusinganewcertificate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution:

At point 3 I needed to put the same alias like in point 1 for last import - domain.com:

```
keytool -import -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -trustcacerts -file domain_com.crt -storepass wso2carbon
```

Now it works great with web browsers but when access with Android it is still not trusted, but that is for another topic.

Comment: Indeed, in the carbon.xml and axis2.xml there's a key alias specified (wso2carbon by default). I theory you could use a different alias, but you need to specify it in the config files too. Indeed, if you keep the original alias name, it will work :)